# Spam protection in web app

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, spam-prevention

I have a web app where users can post comments to it. Is there any plugins or anything that exist so I can scan these messages on their way into the database and only store ones that aren't "spam"?

My app is in ASP.NET MVC 2 and I use JQuery for most of the AJAX posts to store comments, etc.

Edit:

I'm already implementing a "Flag" option, to try and create a self-policing atmosphere on the site, but I'd like there to be something to back that up if the users are too lazy to do anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.stopforumspam.com/ it has an api to detect spammers by IP and/or username

Comment: That's a cool site however we generate a LOT of comments basically all day every day, and it seems they don't want users using their API for that many requests.

Comment: Is this something I would have to download a refresh the database table with everyday (they say they update it once a day) or is it something I could automate my web app to do and refresh the table for me.

Comment: @slandau: it's entirely up to you to update the data in your system as you see fit.